# Error while trying to insert data into sql-alchemy data base (flask)

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying to make a basic quizzing app, when trying to insert data into the database it gives me the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: results.id
[SQL: INSERT INTO results (correct, incorrect) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: (0, 1)]
```

so it is recognizing the data that i'm attempting to enter and it is in seemingly the right format but I dont understand the error as this part of the code does not mention id (i did a similar thing elsewhere in my project and it worked fine)

```
class Results(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    correct = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=False)
    incorrect = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Result ' + str(self.id)


@app.route('/answers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def answers():
    correct = Results.correct
    incorrect = Results.incorrect
    if request.method == 'POST':
        submitted_answer = request.form['answer']
        if submitted_answer == Question.option1:
            correct = int(0)
            incorrect = int(0)
            correct += int(1)
            new_result = Results(correct=correct, incorrect=incorrect)
            db.session.add(new_result)
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            correct = int(0)
            incorrect = 0
            incorrect += int(1)
            new_result = Results(correct=correct, incorrect=incorrect)
            db.session.add(new_result)
            db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/answers')
    all_questions = Question.query.order_by().all()
    all_results = Results.query.order_by().all()
    return render_template('answers.html', questions=all_questions, all_results=all_results)
```

Here is the code in question, sorry if its painful to witness, am new to this and not fully sure on all of the best practices, thanks

full application linked below

https://github.com/turdies/FlaskQuiz

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: added the github link to the post

Comment: How are you creating the tables? Manually or with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: SQLAlchemy is being used

Answer (score 0):

if you want to specify a field as nullable, you want to do the following

```
class Results(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    correct = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    incorrect = db.Column(db.Integer,  nullable=True)
......
```